# PRESERVED_CYCLES in Alphanet

Tags: alphanet

I want to ask about the value of the variable PRESERVED_CYCLES discussed in the [tezos documentation](http://tezos.gitlab.io/mainnet/whitedoc/proof_of_stake.html#baking-rights) in the Alphanet network. I know it is currently equal to 5 in the mainnet network, but I am confused whether it is equal to 2 or 3 in the alphanet network. I know it is a basic information, but somehow I cannot find any official documentation about its current value in Alphanet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ curl -s https://rpcalpha.tzbeta.net/chains/main/blocks/head/context/constants | jq .preserved_cycles
3
```